# android AdMob native ads (and general) questions

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I'm implementing native ads from AdMob, but it's not going well and I have a few general questions:

1) Are native ads from AdMob still in closed beta? If yes, is there a date when it will be open for the public?

2) If it's stil in beta, where do I have to register to become part of the beta-crew and how likely is it, that they accept me?

3) What are these Native Ad Templates? What part of the ad is "templated" since the ads themselves are given by AdMob. Since my native ads dont work yet, I'm kinda confused here.

4) In the AdMob account they talk about "mediating ad networks". Anybody experience with that? When does it make sense to have extra mediator networks instead of just letting AdMob send the ads?